# null value in column "last_login" violates not-null constraint

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, null

Having issues getting rid of this error.

I'm trying to use Digital Ocean to deploy my Django app. I configured Postgres, but when I'm trying to register a new user in my app, I get this problem.

I've tried running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` and they work fine. The SQL migrations are completed upon migration.

Comment: How are you attempting to add the aforementioned user? Via the admin pane or your specific way? What version of Django are you running?

Comment: trying to register the user in a django template so i have form input fields and when i submit the form, the views.py cleans it and saves to db. my version is 1.8.6

Comment: Try add `from django.utils import timezone` and wherever you grab the `user`'s data to save the new `user` add before the save procedure `<user_object>.last_login = timezone.now()`

Comment: @RichardKennethNiescior thanks that did it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try add this to your imports:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

Then wherever you grab the `user`'s data to `save` the new `user` add before the `save` procedure:

```
<user_object>.last_login = timezone.now()
```

Comment: Is there any reason why we can't use a null value for the `last_login` field? According to Django 1.8 release docs, we should be able to use a null value for the `last_login` field of Django's AbstractUser model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#abstractuser-last-login-allows-null-values But I was getting the "not-null constraint" error when `last_login` wasn't defined, which would make sense for Django 1.7, but not for 1.8

Comment: If you haven't run the new migrations from the `django.contrib.auth` package which is bundled with 1.8+ distribution then this hack-job is guaranteed to work in most cases. I feel that there is database-level validation which is altered with the [migration 0005](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0005_alter_user_last_login_null.py).

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I was able to debug this by accessing the psql prompt and running `\d auth_user` (in my case, `auth_user` was the `db_table` name for my AUTH_USER_MODEL), which showed that `last_login` was not nullable. After that, and running `./manage.py showmigrations --list`, I realized that my migrations were incorrectly applied.

Comment: I'm glad this was of some assistance :)

Answer (score 4):

I was upgrading from django 1.7 to django 1.10 when I ran into this. What it ended up being was I needed to run `python manage.py migrate` to update the database tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround and not a solution, but below is a complete example of how to create a user and supply last_login:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

user = User.objects.create_user(
    'username',
    password='password',
    last_login=timezone.now(),
    # Whatever other attributes you want:
    is_superuser=True,
    is_staff=True
)
user.save()
```